# typescript claims JS constructor is "not a constructor function type"

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to import a constructor function from JS and us it in TypeScript.

```
import * as Nanocomponent from 'nanocomponent'
class Dashboard extends Nanocomponent { ... }
```

However, TS complains that `[ts] Type '(name: any) => void' is not a constructor function type.`.  Indeed, Nanocomponent is a function that takes one arg, but it's a constructor.

How do I tip off TS that indeed, Nanocomponent is fact a constructor?

There are a variety of closely related posts, but not quite duplicates from my findings.  Please discuss before flagging it as a dupe.

Comment: Do you have any type definitions for the module ?

Comment: Hello, no.  No type definitions have been made for Nanocomponent yet to my knowledge.